# Firefox addon to force paragraph word-wrapping on both desktop and Android

Tags: android, firefox, desktop-client

Readability is not the answer to this question as indicated in [the graphic below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHw6e.jpg).

Only on Firefox, running both in the desktop and Android versions, I would like to find an add-on (or other configuration option) to allow me to resize the top-level window, or current screen dimensions on Android at all pinch-to-zoom levels, that will cause any and all textual paragraphs to word-wrap to fit within those dimensions.

Key requirements are:

1. Must be on Firefox only.
2. Can be an add-on.
3. If add-on, must participate in Firefox sync so that I can install it once and have it be on both Android and desktop Firefox versions.

[image]